# Wix - Deferred Custom Action fails on Upgrade, resulting in the product being completely removed

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade, rollback, custom-action

***The Setup***

So I have a Custom Action that is marked as Deferred and executes Before InstallFinalize. It looks like this:

```
  <CustomAction Id="CADeferred"
                BinaryKey="binaryCustomActions"
                DllEntry="CADeferredMethod"
                Execute="deferred"/>

  <InstallExecuteSequence>
  ...
  <Custom Action="CADeferred"
          Before='InstallFinalize'>Not Installed or Upgrading</Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And I have Version 1.0 installed currently on the computer environment & fully functional. I then use the Version 2.0 MSI to do an Upgrade.

***The Issue I'm Running Into***

When doing the Upgrade, that Custom Action can fail and returns `ActionResult.Failure`. When that happens, the installer fails and says:

> "Product Setup Wizard ended prematurely because of an error. Your
>   system has not been modified. To install this program at a later time,
>   run Setup Wizard again. Click the Finish button to exit the Setup
>   Wizard."

Once I click Finish. I checked that the product itself has been removed completely from the computer environment. Like it has been uninstalled essentially.

I was hoping it would Rollback to the Version 1.0 as it was before the Upgrade.

***What I'm Trying To Accomplish***

If this scenario happens, I like the installer to Rollback to Version 1.0 on the environment.

***What I've Done So Far***

I've researched on Google for more information on how InstallFinalize works, how Rollbacks work, etc.

From my research, having a Deferred Custom Action to run Before InstallFinalize is the way to go for a Custom Action that needs to modify state on the environment. As well as being able to use the new files on the new installer such as a DLL because it runs "inside" the InstallFinalize step. Since it's defined Before InstallFinalize I thought the Rollback of it would put the system back to the previous installed version of the product.

I've tried making it into a Immediate Custom Action to run After InstallFinalize, but that's bad. If it fails, the product still Upgraded to Version 2.0. Which is odd. Plus I know this is frown upon. So I went to Deferred Custom Action to run Before InstallFinalize.

I also read that usually Deferred Custom Actions have a Rollback Custom Action associated with it. However, due the functionality of the Deferred Custom Action, we can't necessarily fix the issue with a Rollback Custom Action. Reason is because it takes an admin to really check out the failure and manually do any changes needed for a retry of the Upgrade to work the next time. So hence we don't include an associate Rollback Custom Action.

So I'm pretty stumped at this point. Any help or direction would be very much appreciated. If I'm not being clear enough, feel free to ask for more clarification. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the following **MSI SDK** description: [**RemoveExistingProducts Action**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/removeexistingproducts-action). Essentially the placement of the standard action **`RemoveExistingProducts`** will affect how rollback works, and in effect if it works at all. This standard action runs the uninstall of the old setup during a major upgrade - which under the hood is not really an upgrade, but an uninstall of the old product and an install of the new product - with several different "flavors" of sequencing - in other words what happens first, the uninstall or the install.

Late **`RemoveExistingProducts`** sequencing allows proper rollback (details in the SDK article linked to above). For late placement of **`RemoveExistingProducts`** to work correctly, you have to be careful that the component rules are not violated, or files will be missing after the update if you sequence the uninstall late. This is because in this scenario the new version installs as a patch. It patches the changed files and then removes whatever is obsolete. In the early uninstall scenario you "de-couple" yourself from these reference count issues - the old product is completely gone before the new one is installed - and hence you can't roll back to it (unless you manually reinstall it). In other words: early **`RemoveExistingProducts`** it is more forgiving of setup design mistakes - and hence more used in the real world.

The configuration of the major upgrade is determined by either the [MajorUpgrade element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) or [Upgrade Elements](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/upgrade.html).

---

***Some Links***:

- [Doing Major Upgrade in Wix creates 2 entries in Add/Remove Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745912/doing-major-upgrade-in-wix-creates-2-entries-in-add-remove-programs)
- [How do you detect installed product versions at each startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51041639/how-do-you-detect-installed-product-versions-at-each-startup/51052935)
- [How to prevent Wix from installing an older version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072036/how-to-prevent-wix-from-installing-an-older-version)
- <del>[Reboot on install, Don't reboot on uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840273/reboot-on-install-dont-reboot-on-uninstall)</del> (not really relevant, leaving link)
- [Adding entries to MSI UpgradeTable to remove related products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801570/adding-entries-to-msi-upgradetable-to-remove-related-products/51803320#51803320)

Comment: Hi @Stein, good to hear from you (you've helped me once before on a different Wix problem).

Thanks for the info on RemoveExistingProducts. I wasn't aware that this could be moved around and produce different results. I had a feeling the Upgrade was an uninstall of the old version and then a new install of the new version. And now you've clarified that bit of info. 

I'll run this with my team and see if we should look more into moving this step and see the results from it. I'll keep you posted, thanks again.